# Error when starting httpd service "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name using localhost.localdomain

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, hyper-v

I have been following this install for LibreNMS https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-librenms-in-centos/. Everything has been fine until I finally started the httpd service. It spits out this error. I have a virtual host configured. This is the exact Error message:

> Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name using localhost.localdomain. Set the server name directive globally.

I'll display the virtualhost in the httpd config file below.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/librenms/html/
ServerName linuxhelp1.com
CustomLog /opt/librenms/logs/access_log combined
ErrorLog /opt/librenms/logs/error_log
AllowEncodedSlashes On
<Directory "/opt/librenms/html/">
AllowOverride All
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that *linuxhelp1.com* is an example.  You need the actual ServerName, which in this case will be the hyper-v ip address (x.x.x.x).

Add your hyper-v ip address (x.x.x.x) to the ServerName directive both in and outside of the virtualhost container.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/librenms/html/
ServerName x.x.x.x
CustomLog /opt/librenms/logs/access_log combined
ErrorLog /opt/librenms/logs/error_log
AllowEncodedSlashes On
<Directory "/opt/librenms/html/">
AllowOverride All
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Refer to [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-name-based-virtualhost-example/) on using NameVirtualHost and ServerName.  Also, please update your question with the Apache version you are using as 1, 2.2, and 2.4 are all different in their configuration.

For instance, [when upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) you will note that

> The NameVirtualHost directive no longer has any effect, other than to emit a warning. Any address/port combination appearing in multiple virtual hosts is implicitly treated as a name-based virtual host.

Comment: I don't believe it is globally outside of it?

Comment: add the /etc/hosts entry and also make sure ServerName is set outside the vhost directive, restart, and see if the error persists.

Comment: Would it be the linuxhelp1?

Comment: is that a real domain, or just something you were using in your example?  did you register that domain?  it does not appear to be pointing to a server yet.  anyway, if you point that domain in your etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1 and have the global httpd.conf ServerName directive pointed to that, the message may go away.  you can still open the site even though apache is warning you that you aren't ready for going live (which you're not, if your domain name isn't really registered).

Comment: https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-librenms-in-centos/ I've literally followed this. It's supposed to be a real domain? I downlownded libre from it I believe

Comment: did you do this?  `Unwind the Browser and call the URL https://<IP_address>/install.php1` and if so, what <IP_address> did you use?  put that ip address in as the global ServerName and also your vitualhost servername.

Comment: Is that in the conig file for the httpd?  And the only one I ever used was 127.0.0.1. I followed all the steps and it seems that just after the virtual host was created I have gotten errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71835/discussion-between-webjuju-and-legreen95).

Answer (score 0):

That message is just a notice of a default choice, and can be ignored.  To fix the issue generating it, in your main config file outside of any defined hosts/sites add a `ServerName` directive.

EG - on my Debian systems, the main config is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` - at the very bottom simply add

```
ServerName somehost.example.com
```

Of course, that FQDN doesn't need to be in DNS, just in that machines `/etc/hosts` file pointing at 127.0.1.1 (or whatever loopback you like).

IIRC Redhat/CentOS/etc have everything in one big `httpd.conf` file - if that is the case, add the line before you start defining your actual named hosts.

Comment: It has given me an error in my logs unauthenticated agent